# Laravel 8 password confirm middleware usage as API doesn't return a URL for redirection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working inside a Laravel 8 project used as a REST API for a Nuxt JS front-end. I'd like to be able to require the user to confirm their password for some important actions, so in one of my controller's am using the Laravel middleware for `password.confirm` but this is just returning a message to confirm a password, I'm not given any route, I'll need to build a page in my site, and redirect the user there.

What do I need to change in my `update` method to support this?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Brand;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new BrandController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');

        $this->middleware('password.confirm', [
            'only' => ['update']
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'brand' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "One or more fields has been missed or is invalid.",
                'errors' => $validator->messages()
            ], 400);
        }

        // TODO: confirm password...

        $brand = Brand::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                      ->where('slug', $slug)
                      ->first();

        if (!$brand) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "We can't find this brand"
            ], 404);
        }

        try {
            
            $brand->save();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Your brand has been updated",
                'brand' => $brand ?? null
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "We weren't able to update this brand right now."
            ], 422);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the middleware supposed to return a URL?

Comment: When I try to update my form, it throws a 423 error with "Password confirmation required.", well I need this to also return a URL with potentially a token to my front-end so I can redirect the user to a page called "Confirm your password" where they submit the form, and the request continues it's middleware

Comment: why don't you send the password confirm value along with the update request, so before you send the update request to your server, trigger a pop-up that a user can type in their password, which the value then included on the payload and you can capture on your middleware for checking the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a middleware to implement that, just asks the user's password before submitting the request and include it on your payload.

Then on your update method, you can simply apply a validation like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $slug) {

    $request->validate([
        'brand' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|password:api'
    ],[
        'brand.required' => 'You need to specify the brand',
        'password.required' => 'You need to provide a password to perform this request',
        'password.password' => 'The password you have provided is incorrect!'
    ]);

    // All ok, Continue update
    ...
    ...
}
```

there's a `password` validation implemented I think since laravel 6, where it checks the input value and compare it with the current authenticated user password.

Also, when you call `validate` function, it automatically throws back an error if there's any failure so you don't need to manually check if it fails and manually return something.

e.g. if your the password in your payload does not match the current authenticated user password, you'll get a response like this.

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "password": ["The password you have provided is incorrect!"]
    }
}
```